# Battery Charging Current Determination

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging

When charging a battery using a solar panel, or even another battery, how is the current flowing through the battery determined?

Will the internal resistance of the battery draw a certain amount when drained and decrease/increase as it charges? Or is the current simply determined by the builder using a resistor or other loads with the internal resistance being small enough to negate?

Comment: Read-up here: http://batteryuniversity.com ...

Comment: @NickAlexeev - That site should be an answer in itself for almost every battery question on here.

Answer (score 1):

What I have always seen/done is a small-valued resistor (in the range of 0.01-0.05 Ohms; they're called current sense resistors) in between the battery's negative terminal and the system ground. Measuring the voltage at the battery's negative terminal (with respect to system ground) will give you the current flowing into the battery, and you can adjust the applied voltage at the positive terminal to control it.

Answer (score 0):

For some battery chemistries (lead acid) you can rely on internal resistance of the battery to limit the current and charge using constant voltage source. I've seen some cheap/simple lead acid chargers doing that, but oftentimes it's not healthy for a battery.

For a proper charger design you have to measure current and limit it according to what particular battery chemistry likes and in which charging state you it is.